# Which dialects use "fue matado" in place of "fue muerto"?

Tags: participio, voz-pasiva, formas-irregulares

When expressing that someone was killed (*matar*) in the passive voice, the past participle of *morir* is used (suppleting the expected past participle [*matado*](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/28981/20700)):<sup>1 2 3</sup>

> - «Según la leyenda, Osiris, que era el esposo de Isis, **fue muerto** a traición por su propio hermano» <sub>• Pedrero *Besos* [Esp. 1987]</sub>
> - «Imposible saber cuántas personas **fueron muertas** o heridas por las balas» <sub>• Velasco *Regina* [Méx. 1987]</sub>
> - «Selicho **fue muerto** a golpes por sus propios funcionarios» <sub>• Galeano *Días* [Ur. 1978]</sub>
> - El toro **fue muerto** a la tercera estocada.

According to the RAE the regular past participle of *matar* is also used (rarely):<sup>1</sup>

> - «El animal es mío. **Fue matado** en mi propiedad, ¿no, comisario?»  <sub>• RRosa *Sebastián* [Guat. 1994]</sub>

However I have never heard this myself.

**Is this phrasing *("fue matado")* only used in certain dialects or registers? If so, which?**

---

<sup>1. [DPD: **matar(se). 1.**](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=kvCJWyXYED6KELmebz)</sup>
<sup>2. [DPD: **morir(se). 2.**](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=VrHLauG8GD60rDX9OY)</sup>
<sup>3. [DLE: **morir. 7.**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PppPsdZ)</sup>

Comment: I haven't ever used *matar* in passive constructions described. Most naturally, I use *fue asesinado*.

Comment: Not really a duplicate, but [Why is 'estar muerto' used instead of 'ser muerto'?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/793/1674) contains some interesting insights on this.

Comment: In Catalan we say _ser mort_ (ser muerto) and so it must be common to mimic the way of saying and express _ser muerto_ when talking in Spanish.

Comment: [*Hispanic Linguistics at the Crossroads: Theoretical linguistics, language acquisition and language contact*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=CFxACgAAQBAJ&pg=PA98&lpg=PA98) chapter 5 *Fue muerto: Suppletion in Spanish Analytic Passives* (p.89-112) provides more info. @fedorqui the footnote (3) on p.98 goes into a little detail about the Catalan cognates and their productivity in different tenses etc compared to the Spanish ones.

Comment: matado sounds terrible, y prefer "asesinado"

Comment: yo creo que para lo que se le hace a un toro en el ruedo no hay palabras, no es un sacrificio, pero no es una asesinato, simplemente un : "lo mataron de la forma más brutalmente posible"

Comment: What is the dialect here that makes you suppose "fue matado" is used in dialect?

Answer (score 3):

El participio de *matar* es **matado**, de modo que para la formación de los **tiempos compuestos** se usa este participio:

- Lo he matado.       I killed him
- Lo había matado.    I had killed him
- Lo habrá matado.    He will have killed him

En la voz pasiva y cuando se trata de una persona, se emplea casi siempre *el participio* **muerto** en vez del participio *matado*:

- Varios policías **han sido muertos** en un ataque terrorista.

Cuando la muerte no ha sido intencionada, por ejemplo en caso de un accidente, se emplea **resultar muerto**:

- En el accidente de avión **resultaron muertos** 80 pasajeros.

**Expresiones:**

- matar a alguien
- dar muerte a alguien
- quitar la vida a alguien
- fue muerto por ...
- resultaron muertos

*Matar* (su participio matado) me parece la mejor opción. *Asesinar* y *eliminar* conllevan sentidos de premeditación o intento, y por tanto culpabilidad (que legalmente según el jurado, no había). *Matar* como verbo es neutro, simplemente nos explica que, por una acción suya, está muerto alguien.

Yo no he escuchado *ultimar* en este contexto, pero según el DRAE, es americanismo y según el DAA, se usa en todo el continente excepto Colombia, Guatemala, Venezuela y las partes no orientales de Bolivia. No obstante, El País es un periódico español y ya que el único verbo aceptable en España en este contexto es matar (por carecer de otra palabra sencilla neutra en esa tierra), han usado matado.

Comment: Bienvenido. Esperamos ver más respuestas tuyas.

Comment: @DGaleno hola, muchas gracias, si espero ser de utilidad, amm lo único que me falto aclarar es que hablo español latino o internacional, no todo español, por la edición muchas gracias, la había puesto así para denotar las parte importantes de lo que es puro verborreo jejejeje, algo que es importante diferenciar es que el español de españa es CASTELLANO, la lengua de castilla y el mio es español latino

Comment: también me falto mencionar que hay que revisar sinónimos y antónimos, ya que en español tenemos un numero mayor de palabras para describir una sola cosa y en ingles usan la misma palabra para describir muchas cosas

Answer (score 1):

1) «Según la leyenda, Osiris, que era el esposo de Isis, fue muerto a traición por su propio hermano» • Pedrero Besos [Esp. 1987]

Translation: **died by betrayal at the hands of his brother**, In other words,he brother killed him.

2) «Imposible saber cuántas personas fueron muertas o heridas por las balas»

Meaning: died or were wounded (meaning); Translation: were shot to death or wounded by bullets [or gunfire]

3) «El animal es mío. **Fue matado** en mi propiedad, ¿no, comisario?» • RRosa Sebastián [Guat. 1994]

Translated: **was killed**

ser + muerto = to die, in the above examples. killed can also be used in some cases. muerto is the past participle of morir. to die
matar= to kill,fue matado, to be killed

**It's confusing** but in Spanish **fue muerto is actually died but is sometimes was killed, as in an accident**. from: morir. Otherwise, se murió.

> "En resumen, tan correcto es fue muerto como fue matado, pero fue
>   muerto es más frecuente." se le en éste [artículo](https://www.fundeu.es/noticia/los-muertos-que-vos-matais-son-muertos-o-son-matados-3415/)*.

Comment: I bet these downvotes are from non-translators.

Comment: I don't think the OP is asking for translations but usage.

Comment: "When saying someone was killed, matar is occasionally used in the passive voice, where it generally takes the past participle of morir1 2 3". ***That is an incorrect understanding.*** matar is matar and fue muerto is not a replacement for it. So,it does very much involve translation. It is based on a misunderstanding of the Spanish. Matar is to kill as in "He killed the man". Whereas: ser muerto is to die, just like French: être morts. Ser muerto is not to kill.

Comment: http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=Q0MaZUb 

Muerte: accion de "dar muerte" a alguien/ matar quitar vida

Comment: **The OP's question is not "dar muerte".** Of course, dar muerte means to kill. It's  about:  "fue matado" in place of "fue muerto"

Answer (score 0):

In this context I think the word "asesinado" is a better option, but that's only my opinion.

Actually in Spanish we have the "**dar muerte**" verb and its past participle "fue muerto", that would be the closest translation for "**murder**" and "was murdered".

Why I think "asesinado" is a better option? because of the type of murder.

Generally a **murder/dar muerte** is an act of killing someone intentionally, but generally is in a confrontation.

In Spanish there's a huge difference between "matar" and "asesinar": normally **"matar"** is for non human beings and when is not the intention 
while **"asesinar"** is the act of killing someone with intention and even advantage.

So under this context for me killing by betrayal sounds much more like an assassination.

But "dar muerte" would be also correct in the general context and for the same reason that this is a legend and the circumstances are disperse "fue muerto" could be the right option.

Let's go with the case of Jesus Christ. We could argue that he was killed, murdered or assassinated and the three options would be correct because the conditions of his death (pretty much the same as Osiris).

In the end the usage will fall depending of each person point of view:

1.- Accidental/Required : Matar
2.- Confrontation and with intention: Dar muerte
3.- With Intention and Advantage : Asesinar

For a lot of people a bullfight is an act of assassination, for others is a confrontation with the intention of killing and the survivor is the winner so it could be : "fue muerto" or "asesinado"

The interesting case of a man fight:

In a box fight as it would be accidental it would be : "fue matado", but due matado has the animal connotation and would show a lack in respect it is better to just use "murió", but friends, family and even the opponent would feel like "lo maté/mató", but never feel like "asesiné/asesinó"

Comment: here the key word is "NORMALLY"

Comment: The OP posted sentences from the internet, that are fine. The OP is  not asking which is best.The OP is claiming "fue matado comes in place of fue muerto". The bull fue matado (was killed); the others in the OP's examples died (ser muerto). So, in fact, you do not deal with the actual issue that is raised.....

Comment: do i need to add an explanation why matado is for animals an muerto for people ? , also in the bull fight the bull is assassinated too, that's the reason is the "fue muerto" used again.

Comment: matado is normally used when animales are sacrificed (just like slaugther) but then again, the term of matar and dar muerte and asesinar depends of each person's point of view.

Comment: It is not true that matar is for animals and muerto is for people. Matar is kill, look in any dictionary. ser muerto can be die or be killed (sometimes).  It is exactly like French: est mort. and Portuguese: foi morto. Both of which are the verb die or the passive be killed, as in an accident. As for assassinating bulls, that is figurative. Not usual. I don't agree with bullfighting, but don't call it assassination. That is only for human beings.

Comment: not matar, but "matado"

Comment: En resumen, tan correcto es fue muerto como fue matado, pero fue muerto es más frecuente. https://www.fundeu.es/noticia/los-muertos-que-vos-matais-son-muertos-o-son-matados-3415/

Comment: Yup Yup, sobretodo por que "matado" y "Matar" generalmente vienen con una carga emocional, mientras que "fue muerto" cae en la neutralidad de la voz pasiva.