# Are there verbs where the lexical root of the perfect tense forms differs from that of its infinitive form?

Tags: etimología, verbos

Does the Spanish language have any verbs whose perfect tense forms are based on a different lexical root from the infinitive form (by analogy with the Latin verb *fero* > *tuli*)?

Comment: Related Meta question: https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3087/9385

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the highly suppletive verbs [*ser* and *ir*](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/27262/20700), some other verbs have a few non-cognate conjugations:

- the past participle of *matar* is suppleted by *morir* in the passive voice: [*[fue] muerto*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/27354/fue-matado-in-place-of-fue-muerto)
- the impersonal present indicative of *haber*, [*hay*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hay#Spanish) comes from *ha* *i* (< *ahí* < *ibī*)

Some linguists also describe the different conjugations of *caber ~ quepo* etc as "partial suppletion".

---

<sup>[*Introducción a la lingüística*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=45rc8llzOiIC&pg=PA250&lpg=PA250&dq=supleci%C3%B3n+castellano) (p.250)</sup>

Comment: Interestingly, under certain circumstances you can still use *ha*, particularly in time situations: *cinco años ha que hago algo*, although I wouldn't call it interchangeable by any means

Answer (score 2):

It does, they are the irregular verbs, but amongst them the most irregular are the following:

> "ir" in perfect past first person is "fui"
>   "Ser" in perfect past second person is :"fui"

Answer (score 2):

**responder** uses —historically and to a limited extent today— the forms *repuse, repusiste, repuso,* etc.